# Проблема Ubuntu перестал при загрузке дешифровывать диск

Tags: ubuntu, grub, криптография, lvm

У меня на ноутбуке 2 диска, на 1-ом Windows 10, на 1-ом и 2-ом зашифрованные разделы crypto-luks в которых находятся lvm разделы.

Произошла неясная ситуация, запустился под виндой, пользовался офисными программами. Потом перезагрузился под ubuntu и увидел тупо фиолетовый сплеш от grub, перестал запрашивать пароль и грузиться. Линукс не обновлял.

Попробовал загрузиться с live-usb и подцепить разделы в ручную - все ОК.

Но при попытке загрузиться из под Ubuntu (в recovery mode) пишет следующее:

VFS: Cannot open root device "mapper/ubuntu--vg-root" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6

ну и соответственно kernel panic

Что делать ума не приложу =(